# SVC (support vector classification) with categorical (string) data as labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I use `scikit-learn` to implement a simple supervised learning algorithm. In essence I follow the tutorial [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#learning-and-predicting) (but with my own data).

I try to fit the model:

```
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
clf.fit(features_training,labels_training)
```

But at the second line, I get an error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A'`

The error is expected because `label_training` contains string values which represent three different categories, such as `A`, `B`, `C`.

**So the question is:** How do I use SVC (support vector classification), if the labelled data represents categories in form of strings. One intuitive solution to me seems to simply convert each string to a number. For instance, `A = 0`, `B = 1`, etc. But is this really the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features `section 4.3.4  Encoding categorical features.`

In particular, look at using the [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder).  This will convert categorical values into a format that can be used by SVM's.

Comment: You should at least link directly to the section and mention the OneHotEncoder

Comment: But how could hotencoding help you when you will try to predict a new color ? Maybe in your case you have to retrain the model. Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code:

```
from sklearn import svm
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1],[2,3]]
y = ['A', 'B','C']
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
clf.fit(X, y)  
clf.predict([[2,3]])
```

output:
    array(['C'], 
          dtype='|S1')

You should take the dependent variable (y) as 'list'.

Answer (score -1):

Please. No use encoding categorical in SVC. This algoritm work only with continuos variables. "Such integer representation can, however, not be used directly with all scikit-learn estimators, as these expect continuous input, and would interpret the categories as being ordered, which is often not desired (i.e. the set of browsers was ordered arbitrarily)"  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features

Comment: That refers to the OrdinalEncoder and not to the OneHotEncoder which is the right way to proceed in this case. OrdinalEncoder could be dangerous if there isn't a defined order in the categorical variable.