# Building a predictive model with text data and other predictors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, prediction

I'm trying to build a predictive model (random forest, sgd, etc.) using scikit-learn and it seems like every model only allows you to fit text data such as

```py
classifier.fit(X,Y)
```

...where `Y` is the target and `X` is a text feature vector (count_vec -> tf_idf). Is there any way to have a model which in addition to the text feature matrix also contains several categorical variables? Can I simply append them as new columns on the right side of `X`?

Comment: Yes, you can append other categorical columns to the output of text feature vector.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Simply pasting it to the right would provide a meaningful matrix? Or is there anything else to it?

Comment: simple append. Then it depends on your output and requirement. you can change them as required.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert categorical data first - simple appending of string categories to the number values from a feature extractor like TfIdfCountVectorizer will not work. Here's a [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584829/svc-support-vector-classification-with-categorical-string-data-as-labels) on converting categories into numerical feature data that you can append to the right.